# WP Multi Site Header

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a Website on Wordpress and I have enabled Multi Site on it

```
     */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domainname');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/pathofwordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

The Structure of Website is like this domain.com/wordpress/everythinginwordpress
Now I have created a file outside wordpress domain.com/wp-test.php 
and loaded the wp-load function into it

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = "domain.com/pathtowordpress/multisite/";
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
require('pathtowordpress/wp-load.php');

<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Now this wp-load redirects me to the domain.com/pathtowordpress , instead it should fetch the header of the /multisite/
Any help regarding it will be really appreciated

Comment: Why you want to call get_header() function there? Here you should only fetch those data which you want to use.

Comment: I have commented out the get_header() too , Now when i hit the url domain.com/wp-test.php it then takes me to domain.com/pathtowordpress 
I tried to remove the header too but of no use , additionally I was facing the Database Connection Error Until I added 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = "domain.com/pathtowordpress/multisite/";
As told by the http://dovy.io/wordpress/authenticating-outside-of-wordpress-on-diff-domain/

Comment: The issue is that wp-load doesn't work well , it redirects me to the wordpress website , if i comment out the wordpress multisite in config then it works perfect but with multisite enabled it is creating issues